# How to handle a NULL value in reader.GetByte(x)?

Tags: c#, code-behind, datareader

I've got the following block of code:

```
//Check to see if the Unique_ID is 10 or 11 and process accordingly
//10 = Both boxes, 11 = Rework only
if (reader.GetByte(16) == 10)
{
   int ES = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ESCALATED"]);
   if (ES == 0)
   {
      chkEscalated.Checked = false;
   }
   else
   {
      chkEscalated.Checked = true;
      chkEscalated.Visible = true;
      lblEscalated.Visible = true;
      chkRework.Visible = true;
      lblRework.Visible = true;
    }
}
else if (reader.GetByte(16) == 11)
{
}
else
{
}
```

The problem I have is, sometimes, reader.GetByte(16) is NULL.  And when that happens, I get an error:

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

I'm still somewhat of a novice, so I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm missing, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Do the same thing you always do when you need a value that might be `null`; check if it's `null` before using it.

Comment: How would I do that inside the code above?  Could I use the IsNullOrEmpty method, and if so what would the syntax be?  I've never used it in this type of code block.

Comment: You compare it to the null value and see if it is in fact null, like you do with any null value anywhere, ever.  Or, barring that, simply ask Google if you *really* need a way to find out if the value of a cell in a reader is null.  I know you know how to do *that*.

Comment: Your problem isn't with the code you've posted.  Find out why the data in the reader is null.  Now as anon points out, you do want to do the GetByte call once and then check the value in each if statement, otherwise you may fix your immediate issue only to step right into a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
//Check to see if the Unique_ID is 10 or 11 and process accordingly
//10 = Both boxes, 11 = Rework only
if (reader.IsDBNull(16))
{
   //Add here your code to handle null value
}
else
{
   //Use a switch to read the value only one time
   switch (reader.GetByte(16))
   {
     case 10:
       int ES = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ESCALATED"]);
       if (ES == 0)
       {
          chkEscalated.Checked = false;
       }
       else
       {
          chkEscalated.Checked = true;
          chkEscalated.Visible = true;
          lblEscalated.Visible = true;
          chkRework.Visible = true;
          lblRework.Visible = true;
        }
        break;

      case 11:
        break;

      default:
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the one! I'd also recommend replacing the repeated tests of `reader.GetByte(16)` with a `switch`.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really want to read 2 times in the case you miss the first if?
Maybe that's the problem here.
Store the value like `var a = reader.GetByte(16)` and look for that value.
Like that:

```
//Check to see if the Unique_ID is 10 or 11 and process accordingly
//10 = Both boxes, 11 = Rework only 
var a = reader.GetByte(16);
if(a != null)
{
   if (a == 10)
   {
      int ES = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ESCALATED"]);
      if (ES == 0)
      {
         chkEscalated.Checked = false;
      }
      else
      {
         chkEscalated.Checked = true;
         chkEscalated.Visible = true;
         lblEscalated.Visible = true;
         chkRework.Visible = true;
         lblRework.Visible = true;
       }
   }
   else if (a == 11)
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: This would do nothing to prevent the error he's getting.  Also note that getting the value out of a reader is not an expensive operation that needs to be optimized.

Comment: If he stores just one value in the reader he wouldn't get the error. (Updated the answer)

Comment: Yes, he would, because he'd still be trying to convert a null value to a `byte`.  He isn't even able to successfully get the value once, let alone twice.  He'd get the same error, for the same reason, if he executed the line of code you're suggesting.

Comment: Sure.  I most certainly understand it.  It's wrong, and it won't do a thing to prevent the error the OP is getting.  It has the exact same bug that the OP's code has.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error message you posted, it seems that sometimes `reader` is not initialized. Is the `reader` being populated or initialized somewhere? If yes, that's a good place to check. The error message simply means that `reader` is not referencing an existing instance thus it is NULL, and so you cannot call a method on it i.e. you can't call `GetByte()` in it

Comment: The reader isn't null, the value of a column in that row doesn't have a value.

Answer (score -1):

you can add in the if statement `if (reader.GetByte(16) != null && reader.GetByte(16) == 10)` 
this will check if reader.GetByte(16) is null

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.GetByte(16).ToString()))
{
if (reader.GetByte(16) == 10)
{
   int ES = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ESCALATED"]);
   if (ES == 0)
   {
      chkEscalated.Checked = false;
   }
   else
   {
      chkEscalated.Checked = true;
      chkEscalated.Visible = true;
      lblEscalated.Visible = true;
      chkRework.Visible = true;
      lblRework.Visible = true;
    }
}
else if (reader.GetByte(16) == 11)
{
}
else
{
}
}
```

Try This.